# Using `fork()` to create child process and grandchild process and count total number of created process from parent (main process)

Tags: c, process, operating-system, pipe, fork

I was solving problems regarding `fork()` and I came across this problem.

> Consider the following code snippet in your main function -
>
> ```
> a = fork();
> b = fork();
> c = fork();
> ```
>
> Now, write the full program, that will check the children’s PID and if it is odd then the process will create another child process. Lastly, print how many processes have been created considering the first parent process.

I tried approaching this problem using `pipe()` for interprocess communication.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {

    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);           // defining pipe for interprocess communication

    int x = 0;
    int i = 1;

    pid_t a, b, c;

    a = fork();
    b = fork();
    c = fork();

    if (a == 0) {
        printf("a pid: %d\n", getpid());
        if (getpid()%2) {
            pid_t gc_id_1 = fork();
            if (gc_id_1 == 0) {
                printf("gc_id_1 pid: %d when a pid is %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                write(fd[1], &x, sizeof(int));
                return 0;
            }
        }

        write(fd[1], &x, sizeof(int));

        return 0;
    }

    if (b == 0) {
        printf("b pid: %d\n", getpid());
        if (getpid()%2) {
            pid_t gc_id_2 = fork();
            if (gc_id_2 == 0) {
                printf("gc_id_2 pid: %d when b pid is %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                write(fd[1], &x, sizeof(int));
                return 0;
            }
        }

        write(fd[1], &x, sizeof(int));

        return 0;
    }

    if (c == 0) {
        printf("c pid: %d\n", getpid());
        if (getpid()%2) {
            pid_t gc_id_3 = fork();
            if (gc_id_3 == 0) {
                printf("gc_id_3 pid: %d when c pid is %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                write(fd[1], &x, sizeof(int));
                return 0;
            }
        }

        write(fd[1], &x, sizeof(int));

        return 0;
    }

    close(fd[1]);

    if (a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0) {
        wait(NULL);
        while (read(fd[0], &x, sizeof(int)) != 0) {     // man 2 read
            i++;
        }

        printf("Total process created : %d\n", i);
    }

    close(fd[0]);

    return 0;

}
```

I don't have any clue if my program is right or wrong.
Now my question is, is this the right way to approach this problem, and can this be solved more efficiently?

Comment: Generally I suggest you use pen and paper to draw the process tree created from your code. Unfortunately the loop is not deterministic so that part will not really be possible to do using pen and paper, or any other manual technique. You have to build the program, and add lots of debugging output after every `fork` call. And know that the number of calls to `fork` could vary from run to run.

Comment: On another note, if you have the same code in two or more places, then use a *function*.

Comment: Make sure you use enough debugging output.  For a case like this, make sure that processes report at least their own PID and optionally their PPID (parent PID) in each output (`printf("%5d:%5d: …\n", getpid(), getppid(), …);`) so that you can track what's going on more easily.  The newlines at the end of the format string are beneficial; consider whether you should use `fflush(stdout);` after calls to `printf()`, and also consider whether the diagnostics would be better going to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how to use function in case like this. don't you think it will make things more messy?

Comment: the output is `11` sometimes `12` do you guys think this is right? or should it be more?

Comment: Functions make the code cleaner, easier to read and understand, easier to maintain, and easier to debug. Take the maintenance point, for example, what if you need to make a small change in the code? Now you must make it at three places, increasing the risk of mistakes. If you have a function you only need to make the change once.

Comment: On another couple of notes, the loop `while (read(fd[0], &x, sizeof(int)) != 0)` can become infinite if there's an error and `read` starts to return `-1`. And `if (a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0)` doesn't make a difference between a successful fork or a failed one. And `wait(NULL);` only waits for *one* child process to finish.

Comment: And 11 or 12? I don't know, I think it sounds a bit small. You have the possibility to create more processes than that. How many outputs do you get for "a pid", "b pid"  and "c pid"? The sum of those printouts will be the *minimum* value you can get, with the maximum being double that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I understand all of those you pointed out about function. but my question is how to use it in this case (while forking in different case) can you please give me a snippet of how you would have done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the optimal solution for the above problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main() {

    pid_t a, b, c;
    int x = 0;
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);               // defining pipe for interprocess communication

    a = fork();
    b = fork();
    c = fork();
    
    if (a>0 && b>0 && c>0) {

        // waiting for all the child process to finish their execution
        while (wait(NULL) != -1 || errno != ECHILD);

        close(fd[1]);
        
        int i=1; 

        while (read(fd[0], &x, sizeof(int)) != 0) {
            i++;
        }
        printf("Total processes: %d\n", i);
        close(fd[0]);
    } else {

        printf("In child %d\n", getpid());
        write(fd[1], &x, sizeof(int));
        pid_t gc = -1;

        if (getpid() % 2) {
            gc = fork();
            if (gc == 0) {
                write(fd[1], &x, sizeof(int));
                printf("Inside fork %d my parent %d\n", getpid(), getppid()); 
                return 0;
            }
        }

        // waiting for grand child process to finish its execution
        if (gc != -1) {
            waitpid(gc, NULL, 0);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    return 0;

}
```